Thingsboard build APK error in Android Studio
When I try to build the APK, this error occurred:
C:\Dev\thingsboard_app\flutter_thingsboard_app\lib\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color build apk

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                        

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\flutter_thingsboard_app\android\build.gradle' line: 13

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Could not create task ':app:copyFlutterAssetsRelease'.
      > Could not create task ':app:mergeReleaseAssets'.
         > Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method IncrementalTask.taskAction$gradle_core() because interface org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid parameter to an action method.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\flutter_thingsboard_app\android\build.gradle' line: 13

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Could not create task ':app:copyFlutterAssetsRelease'.
      > Could not create task ':app:mergeReleaseAssets'.
         > Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method IncrementalTask.taskAction$gradle_core() because interface org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid parameter to an action method.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

BUILD FAILED in 1m 50s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          112.0s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

I have Java version as follows:
PS C:\flutter_thingsboard_app> java --version
openjdk 17.0.13 2024-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.13+11 (build 17.0.13+11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.13+11 (build 17.0.13+11, mixed mode, sharing)

My Android build.gradle is as follows
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

And my gradle-wrapper.properties looks like this:
 distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME distributionPath=wrapper/dists zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME zipStorePath=wrapper/dists distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.6-all.zip

I have tried to amend the Java level and Gradle level according to this list, but still doesn't work.

Hey Chris, try any of these 2 things let's see. First, change jcenter() to mavenCentral(), and  if that doesn't work then downgrade the Gradle from 8.6 to 7.6.3

Thanks, Christophy! Unfortunately, I still see the same error after making those changes. Do you have any other suggestions?

Okay! Change the gradle to 7.3.3 and if it's no different, try 7.2.1
